# Ubuntu 16.04 distorted loading image and Graphic after unlock

Tags: 16.04, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTE on my Sony Vaio Laptop having below configuration:

- Ram: 4GB
- Graphic Card: AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series [1024 MB]
- Processor: Intel i5-3230M @2.60GHz

Ubuntu is installed successfully. But when I boot into Ubuntu I'm getting distorted UBUNTU loading logo as show below:

[image]

After loading everything works fine until I locked the system. Once I locked the system its graphic becomes distorted and unresponsive as shown below:

[image]

graphic_issue:

[image]

Please help me to fix this issue.

As per requirement, below are details:

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [1002:6841]
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [104d:90ab]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

[`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`](//paste.ubuntu.com/19524587/) (there were lot of entries in this file, so I attached some piece of information from it).

Comment: Have you checked for [additional-drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers) to see if you can get more robust performance.

Comment: @user176105 i'm getting below options under additional drivers option:

Using processor microcode firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode(proprietary)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have made the required changes in question.

Comment: Thank you @DavidFoerster, I have added the output using pastie service.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't find anything obvious in the log. It may be worth trying the proprietary driver released by AMD from the *Additional Drivers* applications like @user176105 mentioned.